# Export FLA composition to FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, flash, button, export, movieclip

Is it possible to export FLA composition to Flex? So it will work exactly as in Flash Pro but instead in FLEX? FLA contains a bunch of movieClips, buttons, images, all driven by an .as file.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Publish to a SWF then you can either embedd the SWF in your Flex app or load it using the SWFLoader.

Embedding info:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=embed_4.html

SWFLoader: 
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/SWFLoader.html

Comment: no, I meant transferring it, so I can call all the parameters and everything from flex, not just swf transfer

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you mean.  You can definitely bring your code over from Flash Pro to Flash Builder. copy and paste.  But there is no parallel for the asset library or for maintaining graphical assets in the Flash Builder tooling. You'll have to embed them; either as images or as a swf or load them at runtime. You can access library items from a swf directly from Flex. More info on this page: http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=853

Answer (score 0):

You can check off "export SWC" in your Flash publish settings, then add that SWC to your Flex project's library path.  You can then use any of the classes compiled in that SWC in your project.